# 301 working on some URLs and not on others in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi I am having an issue with .htaccess on 301 redirects.

Everything looks fine, on 90% of the urls but not for any of the individual blog post redirects.

here is the code where they do not redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^blog-article.php?id=38 blog-post/xxxx-xxxxxx-xx-x-xxxxxxx/9/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog-article.php?id=34 blog-post/xxxxxxx/4/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

But the all of the other 301 rewrites work, and they look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^old-url-portfolio/(.*)$ page/new-url-portfolio/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^Portfolio/Detail/(.*)$ portfolio/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^old-url/7/ page/new-url/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact-us-old/ page/contact-us-new/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog.php page/blog/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

I can not find why they are not working, its not because the ones that are not working are individual files because the blog.php file is being sent to the new page.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not match against querystring in RewriteRule's pattern. To redirect **blog-article.php?id=123** to diffrent location , you need to match against %{QUERY_STRING} using RewriteCond directive.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$
RewriteRule ^blog-article.php$ /location/? [L,R]
```

Note :The traling **?** at the end of the destination path is important as it discards the old querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around, it seams the issue is the ?id=number so I simply did this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=38$
RewriteRule ^blog-article\.php$ http://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/blog-post/xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx/9/ [R=301,L]
```